# Apache2 loads slow - free resources

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, mpm-prefork, mpm-worker

My site needs about 10 - 12 seconds to load, even if the cpu is just by 10% and the ram by 20%.

This is my apache2 setting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrlNz.png

It was even worse some days ago, so I turned `keepalive off`, that made it better.

How can I change it so the site is running faster, and uses all resources?

Comment: Is your question about a lack of MPM, or performance problems?

Comment: I think the first is the reason for the second. @womble

Comment: Please stick to one question.  Either the lack of MPM or a performance problem.

Comment: The performance problem is what I want to solve, I have changed my question. Thanks for that hint.